# Creating Variant array of strings (mixed data of Numbers or Strings)

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a new VBA based excel sheet to allow the user to input some data and calculate a result for them based off some back-end standards/calculations.

Data input is via three columns. The first lists a code for the product. Depending on the product it will need to also have either column 2 or 3 populated by the user. On another sheet is all the fixed data behind the calculations including two lists which contain all products (each product is only ever in one list). Depending on which list the product is in determines which column is required to be populated and the other column is changed to a predetermined value (1 or an empty cell depending on which list the product is in). The non required cell is then locked so the user can't even select it whilst the other column remains unlocked and able to have data input.

I've tried a few different things to get this to work, none have worked thus far short of manually coding each item into the VBA code which is bad practice if the data lists are going to change. Did prove that the rest of the code seems to work just fine and the cells change/lock/unlock as required if I manually code them in however so that's a start.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ProductListA() As String
Dim ProductCountA As Integer

ProductCountA = Worksheets("Data").Range("D4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
'determines how many products are in the list

ReDim ProductListA(ProductCountA ) As String
ProductListA= Worksheets("Data").Range("D4").CurrentRegion.Value
'resizes ProductListA and populates with data from list, list is dynamically sized to account for any additions without needing to update code

'all above declarations etc is replicated for ProductListB with its corresponding list

'Checks if target is in either list
If IsInArray(Target.Value, ProductListA) Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = False
ElseIf IsInArray(Target.Value, ProductListB) Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""    
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True
End If
End Sub

'Function checks if the target is in array
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

One of two things seem to happen:

1. I define the product list as a string, falls over when it tries to assign the data to it with type mismatch, probably from the multiple lines of items in the product list being unable to assign to a single string.
2. I define the product list as a variant, code runs and list is built as a variant of strings. If the user input contains letters it works fine. But if the value in the product list is a number only it's assigned as a variant-integer rather than variant-string. When it comes to checking if the data the user enters is in the product list, it won't find it as its trying to compare a string to an integer etc and just ignores it.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I feel as though I'm pretty close but am just missing one little thing.

Comment: Why not use `VarType()` or  `TypeName()` to determine the variable type, and then go from there? If it determines the variable to be an integer you could use `Str()` to convert the item in the array to a string, to ensure the checking is performed correctly.

Comment: You can leave the product lists on the sheet and use Match directly against the ranges - it will be fast and there's no need for any conversions.  Also - how is the sheet protected?  The locking will have no effect if it's not.  Plus - its' not good to update the same sheet where you just captured the change event: it will trigger again etc etc.  Did you leave anything out which deals with that?

Comment: @TimWilliams. Sheet protections are turned off/on whenever the code enters an area where the VBA takes over and starts changing things (left out as I thought they weren't necessarily relevant to the issue at hand). This seemed logical to me however as I'm still relatively fresh to VBA if there is a better way I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @TimStack trying to avoid doing that as I thought there had to be a better way to do it. If I run out of solutions/ideas that will be the backup option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to my comments above:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ProductA As Boolean, ProductB As Boolean

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub  'too many cells
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub           'for example

    If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
    'easier to use Match directly against the worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        ProductA = Not IsError(Application.Match(Target.Value, _
                                   .Range("D4").CurrentRegion, 0))
        If Not ProductA Then
            ProductB = Not IsError(Application.Match(Target.Value, _
                                   .Range("F4").CurrentRegion, 0))
        End If
    End With
    End If 'anything to look up

    If ProductA Or ProductB Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(ProductA, 1, "")
        'protect/unprotect sheet ?
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = IIf(ProductA, True, False)
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = IIf(ProductA, False, True)
    Else
        'you should decide here if you need to reset anything when a user
        '  clears a cell which might have previously had a Product....
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the way this flows and works however I still can't get it to work. I have however managed to isolate it down to something to do with the CurrentRegion portion of the Match function. If I remove that and specify a region e.g. Range("D4:D8") it works. However if I leave it as Range("D4").CurrentRegion it simply won't work and won't match anything at all (alpha or numeric in list or input). Tried the other answer on this post quickly and I'd say its the same issue. There is clear space for 1 cell around all sides of the current region and D4 is the top left cell of the group

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ProductListA()
Dim ProductCountA As Integer

ProductCountA = Worksheets("Data").Range("D4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
'determines how many products are in the list

ReDim ProductListA(ProductCountA )
ProductListA= Worksheets("Data").Range("D4").CurrentRegion.Value
'resizes ProductListA and populates with data from list, list is dynamically sized to account for any additions without needing to update code

'all above declarations etc is replicated for ProductListB with its corresponding list

'Checks if target is in either list
If IsInArray(Target.Value, ProductListA) Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = False
ElseIf IsInArray(Target.Value, ProductListB) Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""    
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True
End If
End Sub

'Function checks if the target is in array
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```